# Merging cells in HTML ruins the layout

Tags: html

I am working on my project at the moment, so I tried to create a time table but the problem is when I go to merge two or more cells it would ruin the entire layout and creating an extra cell on the right hand side.

I dont know how to add the code, but please click on the links so you can see what I am talking about.
https://gyazo.com/2d3367a8c79f42d5b2e44a3182f10c20

https://gyazo.com/4c8a396173ee8282649a2cca846eaeee

Comment: please post an example, or code to make your question understandable

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, sorry I am new to stackoverflow so I dont know how to add the code.

Comment: first why you merge vertical cells using rowspan, and second its normal behavior for html table, if you can post an image for what you want it to look like, I might be able to help you

Comment: Then what do I use to merge vertical cells? I would like to have it so that all the cells that are covered by the X are blank. https://gyazo.com/21c41caca37f2caaa776f8f75c52864c

Answer (score 0):

When you go to merge two or more cells in a column you mast delete the cell in a neighbor row.
When you go to merge two or more cells in a row you mast delete the cell in the same row.

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
//  <td>&nbsp;</td> this is for delete
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
//  <td>&nbsp;</td> this is for delete
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```